Can't install RT::Extension::LDAPImport
I installed the application tracker version 5 on ubuntu server 22.04. Everything is working well, the tracker is running. But when trying to install sudo cpan -i RT::Extension::LDAPImport, an error appears.
nicolay@nicolay:~/rt-extension-ldapimport-multiemail$ sudo cpan -i RT::Extension::LDAPImport
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 21 Apr 2024 16:17:01 GMT
Running install for module 'RT::Extension::LDAPImport'
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AL/ALEXMV/RT-Extension-LDAPImport-0.36.tar.gz ok
Configuring A/AL/ALEXMV/RT-Extension-LDAPImport-0.36.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Cannot determine perl version info from lib/RT/Extension/LDAPImport.pm
Cannot find the location of RT.pm that defines $RT::LocalPath in: inc /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34 /usr/share/perl/5.34 /usr/local/lib/site_perl . /usr/local/lib /usr/lib
Path to directory containing your RT.pm:
No 'Makefile' created  ALEXMV/RT-Extension-LDAPImport-0.36.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK

All dependencies are fixed. Including this addiction. I can't install the module either manually or as a package in any way. Help. Also, the sudo cpan -i RT:: Auth::ExternalAuth module cannot be installed

I know that these modules included on request tracker 4 above. But when run is run import users from Active Directory happen error. Error point out that the module ldap necessary install.
